# Routing for api REST in php mvc

Tags: php, rest, url-routing

I want create mvc structure using routing i do something like this
`$router->add('/',['controller'=> 'home', 'action'=>'index']);`
`$router->add('{controller}/{action}'); // general case`
`$router->add('admin/{controller}/{action}',['namespace' => 'admin');`
So urls:
 Site/ Site/home/index 
Site/admin/users/all
Site/controller/action

---

This works with web pages but the problem how to add routes for API RESTfull ? I try something like this  `$router->add('api/{controller}',['namespace'=>'api']);` Without seting action because its bad practice to add the verb in url like this  site/api/users/getAll Its must be like this  Site/api/users
----
 So how i can do this with my router ? Any help ?

Comment: You really should watch [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM) and read [this article](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). Also, just because you call something "controller" does not make it MVC.

Comment: @teresko So can give me good lectures/articles about MVC and routing ?